# JQuery: Scrolling images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I would like to develop a scrolling function (on images) like on this site [bethellery.com](http://bethellery.com/2015/winter/). At the moment, my code is kind of working, but I have a major problem: the size of the scrolling bar is nearly as big as my div size, so I can't scroll that much.

Here is the html:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="img-inner" id="img-1" style="display: block" >
        <img class="img" src="src-1" alt="alt-1" />      
    </div>

    <div class="img-inner" id="img-2" style="display: none" >
        <img class="img" src="src-2" alt="alt-2" />      
    </div>

    <div class="img-inner" id="img-3" style="display: none" >
        <img class="img" src="src-3" alt="alt-3" />      
    </div>

    <div class="img-inner" id="img-4" style="display: none" >
        <img class="img" src="src-4" alt="alt-4" />      
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the css:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 100%;
}

#container {
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

.img-inner{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Here is the js:

```
var lastScrollTop = 0;
var x = 1;

$('#container').scroll(function(event){
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();

    if(st > lastScrollTop){
        //downscroll code       
        document.getElementById('img-'+x).style.display = "none";
        //if next image isn't the last image
        if((x+1) !== 4){
            x=x+1;
        }
        document.getElementById('img-'+x).style.display = "block";
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById('img-'+x).style.display = "none";
        if((x-1) !== 0){
            x=x-1;
        }
        document.getElementById('img-'+x).style.display = "block";
    }
    lastScrollTop = st;
});
```

I don't really know what is happening but I think due to the fact the display styles of the div are none, the scroll doesn't detect the flow under the first image.

On the site above, scroll bar size is clearly adapting itself to the numbers of images the div contains.

Thank you very much and have a great day.

Comment: use overflow:scroll; may be

Comment: It doesn't change anything, thanks btw for the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that `display: none;` turns off the display of an element, so it has no effect on layout ([MDN's words](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display)), meaning any calculations that involve it simply won't.

This is demonstrated by the [following JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gy8hrogm/1/) (your code) - now two images are set to `display: block;` and the scroll bar shows this.

Try using `visibility: hidden;` instead, as [demonstrated here](https://jsfiddle.net/gy8hrogm/2/). Visibility leaves [an elements space occupied](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility) while not showing it. It's effect is like `opacity`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, i'm trying it right now. There are still some problems and I'll come back to you if i can't fix them.

Comment: Indeed the visibility option leaves a blank space when set to hidden. The scroll bar is working well though. Unfortunately it is not the effect wanted.

Comment: @v5ono it does solve the problem in the question (that the scroll bar wasn't responding to the internal elements) so you can mark accepted if you like :-) - if you have another problem, then ask another question, but make sure you check through the suggested questions as there might already be one that answers it :-)